# Ksh and Vi scripting

Tags: scripting, edit, vi, ksh

and I'm used to vi not vim. For my work I am currently trying to make a script using ksh and vi. What I want to do is be able to open and search a file for key terms and extract information. For example I would like to run a ksh script that searches a file for the key term 'subject' and then extract the information 'line one'. The reason I want to use vi is because I then want to write to a file the values I have extracted into one line delimited by commas.

```
Subject: line one
Content: line two
```

Thank you for any help and references.

Edit: Yes using sed, awk, and grep is a more effective way. But I have a problem assigning my result to a variable in ksh, currently I have :

```
testing=grep Primary /u/mtjandr/temp.txt | sed -e 's/[:a-zA-Z]* //g' 
grep Primary /u/mtjandr/temp.txt | sed -e 's/[:a-zA-Z]* //g'
```

By itself it ouputs the right result but when I try assigning it to a variable I get erorr

> copy_group.sh[18]: Primary: not found.

**Update**: I found my solution:

```
testing=`grep Primary /u/mtjandr/temp.txt | sed -e 's/[:a-zA-Z]* //g'`
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you must use `vi.` There are many other simpler ways of achieving that using tools there were designed for that very purpose, e.g. `sed`, `awk`, `grep`.

Comment: ... also, to improve your chances of getting a reasonable answer you might want to also include an *example of your expected output* and and description of [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your file probably looks regular, you would want to look into [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) as Shawn mentioned. `Grep` gives you the lines you are interested, `awk` extracts the fields and `sed` edits the whole thing.

So in your example, you would want to find the lines containing `Subject`:

```
grep Subject file
```

and extract `line one`:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s,", $2, $3}'
```

and finally remove the extra `,` inserted in the end of the file

```
sed 's/,$//'
```

These three commands need to be piped together:

```
grep Subject file | awk '{printf "%s %s,", $2, $3}' | sed -e 's/,$//'
```

Of course, the `awk` part needs to be customized to your exact file structure.

Finally, to write the whole thing in another file (instead of output), you can redirect the output of the command above to a file:

```
grep Subject file | awk '{printf "%s %s,", $2, $3}' | sed -e 's/,$//' > other_file
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated on comments above, there are many other simpler ways of achieving that using tools there were designed for that very purpose, e.g. `sed`, `awk`, `grep`.

If you do decide to give something other than `vi` a go, then here's a version using a single `awk` command:

```
awk '/^Subject: /{printf "%s%s",x,substr($0,10);x=","}' in.txt > out.txt
```

Example:

```
[me@home]$ cat in.txt
Subject: line one
Content: line two
Subject: line three
yadda yadda

[me@home]$ awk '/^Subject: /{printf "%s%s",x,substr($0,10);x=","}' in.txt > out.txt
[me@home]$ cat out.txt
line one,line three
```

The `x=','` bit is so we can prefix all output apart from the first one with a comma. For something more readable, we can simply change the output record separator (ORS) from `\n` to a comma. This howerer will lead to a trailing comma which we need to remove with another command.

In this example, we pipe the output to `sed` to remove the trailing separator:

```
awk -v ORS=',' '/^Subject: /{print substr($0,10)}' in.txt | sed -e 's/,$//' > out.txt
```

Breakdown of the command:

```
awk -v ORS=',' '/^Subject: /{print substr($0,10)}' in.txt | sed -e 's/,$//' > out.txt
    _________   __________   ___________________   ______   _______________ _________
       |             |               |                |             |           |
 separate output     |          OUtput the line       |      Remove trailing    |
 records with        |           from char 10         |           comma         |
 comma (not \n)      |             onwards            |                         |  
                     |                                |                  Redirect output
             Match lines that                    input file                to out.txt
           start with "Subject :"
```